# Wired connection fails on 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, dns, ethernet

I have been using Ubuntu for a few years now, and since I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 I have this issue, where I get no error or notifications at all, but my wired connection just stops working. The connection stops working when I open a webbrowser, use terminal to update or whatever I am doing. The only thing that doesn't let the connection being dropped seems to be dropbox and skype.

I noticed some changes in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Which contains this line when the connection is still working:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And contains this line after it stops working:

```
search lan
```

Changing anything in this file doesn't seem to work, neither does `sudo service network-manager restart` do anything useful.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 eth`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)<br>
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:050e]<br>
Kernel driver in use: atl1c
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
    *-network              
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: b8:70:f4:6d:78:cc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.30 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:53 memory:c0200000-c023ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 00
       serial: c0:f8:da:54:15:0d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0100000-c0103fff
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces[5] file used by ifup[8] and ifdown[8]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I also read about this bug: [Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842)
And was told to quote out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and restart network manager.

None of this worked. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be due to the incompatibility of the built-in driver in Ubuntu 13.04 release.

1. Download compat-drivers source code: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
2. Extract the tarball and type the following commands on a terminal:

> cd [path-to-extracted-driver]
>
> ./scripts/driver-select alx
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

1. Reboot the system.

Comment: Hmm... when I want to connect to a wireless connection it crashes(again).... I guess no wired connection and wired at the same time. (I use a vm which connects through wireless to a different network).